# Split and process XML file

Tags: xml, perl

I have an `original.xml` file structured like so:

```
<root>
    <parent attr1="val1" attr2="val2" ... >
        <child key1="val3" key2="val4" ... />
        <child key1="val5" key2="val6" ... />
        ...
    </parent>
    ...
    <parent attr1="val7" attr2="val8" ... />
    ...
</root>
```

For each `parent` node of this file I need to create a new file, name it according to the value of `attr1` attribute and insert this data:

```
<newroot>
    <newparent attr1="val1" attr2="val2" ... />
</newroot>
```

For that, I'm using this perl one-line command:

```
perl -p -i -e 'open(F, ">", "new/".($1).".xml") if /<parent attr1="(.*)" attr2="(.*)" ... /; print {F} "<newroot><newparent attr1=\"".($1)."\" attr2=\"".($2)."\" /></newroot>";' "original.xml"
```

This works good enough for all the original `parent`s with no `child`ren. But for each `parent` that has `child`ren (let's say the first `parent` in my example), it multiplies the output for as many rows as the `parent` has, like so:

```
<newroot>
    <newparent attr1="val1" attr2="val2" ... />
</newroot>
<newroot>
    <newparent attr1="" attr2="" ... />
</newroot>
<newroot>
    <newparent attr1="" attr2="" ... />
</newroot>
...
<newroot>
    <newparent attr1="" attr2="" ... />
</newroot>
```

I don't quite understand why this happens. How do I make my perl command output only one `newroot` element with the needed data?

Comment: Have you though about doing it with XSLT? I think libxslt can be used from Perl and it supports exsl:document http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html so there you could have a proper handling of XML.

Comment: Unfortunately I know next to nothing about XSLT. I'll surely have to dedicate a few weeks to get a firm grip of it, but with this particular problem it feels like it would take too long to switch to XSLT since it's almost done, just this one bug spoiling it all.

Comment: `if /.../; print "...";` strikes me as strange: what is the if going to achieve if there is nothing within the if block?

Comment: @bytepusher: That's `if` as a statement modifier. Its `open(...) if /.../;`

Comment: @bytepusher I'm not sure if I understand. I need the `if` block so that I can reuse the attribute values.

Comment: I dunno why I read in half sentences today. never mind me, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use XSLT to solve that, for instance LibXSLT has support for `exsl:document` (see http://exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/index.html) and that way you can write an XSLT stylesheet doing

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
  extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
  exclude-result-prefixes="exsl"
  version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="root/parent[@attr1]" mode="new"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent" mode="new">
  <xsl:message>Writing file <xsl:value-of select="@attr1"/></xsl:message>
  <exsl:document href="{@attr1}.xml" method="xml" indent="yes">
    <newroot>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </newroot>
  </exsl:document>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="parent">
  <newparent>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  </newparent>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which splits the XML input document, creating one result file for each `root/parent` element with an `attr1` attribute, creating a new root in those files named `newroot`, transforming the `parent` element to `newparent` and copying its attributes.

You can run a stylesheet in Perl using

```
  use XML::LibXSLT;
  use XML::LibXML;

  my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new();

  my $source = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'original.xml');
  my $style_doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'sheet1.xsl');

  my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet($style_doc);

  my $results = $stylesheet->transform($source);

  print $stylesheet->output_as_bytes($results);
```

As you have indicated in your comment that you have run into memory and/or performance problems, here is an alternative approach making use of `LibXML::Reader` which is a forwards reading pull parser and does not load the complete XML into an in memory tree structure:

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use XML::LibXML::Reader;
  use XML::LibXML;

  my $reader = XML::LibXML::Reader->new(location => "input.xml")
         or die "cannot read file.xml\n";

  while ($reader->read) {
    processNode($reader);
  }

  sub processNode {
      my $reader = shift;

      if ($reader->nodeType == XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT && $reader->name eq "parent")
      {
        my $clone = $reader->copyCurrentNode(0);
        $clone->setName('newparent');

        my $doc = XML::LibXML::Document->new( );
        $doc->setDocumentElement($doc->createElement('newroot'));
        $doc->documentElement()->appendChild($clone);

        my $filePrefix = $clone->getAttribute('attr1');
        my $fileName = "$filePrefix-result.xml";
        print "Writing file $fileName.\n";

        $doc->toFile($fileName, 1);

      }
  }
```

It should avoid the memory problems, I hope.

Comment: Martin thanks a lot. This works great. But there's one thing I forgot to mention. My `original.xml` has over **one million** `parent` tags. When I run your code, it does work as intended, but it completely blocks my computer. It would take hours, if not days to complete it all. On the other hand, my previous script was significantly faster and more efficient. This is why I decided to use it in the first place. Is there any way to just stick to perl?

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ, I have added an alternative approach that should perform better when reading huge files.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex. Use a parser. I quite like [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm). (`XML::LibXML` is pretty good too).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new->parsefile('your_source.xml');

foreach my $parent_elt ( $twig->findnodes('//parent') ) {
    #remove children if that's what you want?
    $_->delete for $parent_elt->children();
    my $newname = $parent_elt->att('attr1');
    print "Opening:", $newname, "\n";
    my $new_doc = XML::Twig->new->set_root( XML::Twig::Elt->new('newroot') );
    $parent_elt->cut;
    $parent_elt->paste( $new_doc->root );

    $new_doc -> set_pretty_print ('indented_a'); 
    open( my $output, '>', "$newname.xml" ) or die $!;
    print {$output} $new_doc->sprint;
    close($output);
}
```

Given your sample data, this does approximately what you want.

OK, so the thing you *didn't* mention:

> Martin thanks a lot. This works great. But there's one thing I forgot to mention. My original.xml has over one million parent tags.

Is quite important - XML is a tag-matching process, which means it can't be sure it's finished and the XML is valid until it reaches the end. That normally means parsing the whole document to verify that the tags are matched.

One of the drawbacks of XML is that it's memory footprint is often around 10x the file size.

However, `XML::Twig` has another useful feature - `twig_handlers` and `purge`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

sub extract_parent_elt {
    my ( $twig, $parent_elt ) = @_;

    #remove children if that's what you want?
    $_->delete for $parent_elt->children();

    #pick out the attr for our file name
    my $newname = $parent_elt->att('attr1');
    print "Opening:", $newname, ".xml\n";

    #create a new document - insert a 'newroot' as it's root element. 
    my $new_doc = XML::Twig->new->set_root( XML::Twig::Elt->new('newroot') );
    #cut and paste this element into the new doc. 
    $parent_elt->cut;
    $parent_elt->paste( $new_doc->root );
    #note - because we're purging and not saving the 'old' doc, a
    #cut doesn't modify the original. 

    #open output:
    open( my $output, '>', "$newname.xml" ) or die $!;
    #note - pretty print has some limitations. 
    #specifically - there are some XML things that it breaks. 
    #your code doesn't _appear_ to have these. 
    $new_doc -> set_pretty_print('indented_a'); 
    print {$output} $new_doc->sprint;
    close($output);

    #discard everything so far.
    $twig->purge;
}

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 
                twig_handlers => { 'parent' => \&extract_parent_elt } );

$twig -> parsefile('original.xml');
```

The handler fires on finding a matched 'close' element, and gets handed that chunk of XML. `purge` tells twig to discard anything that's been processed thus far (e.g. any that have had 'closed' tags).

Comment: Sobrique thanks a lot. I tried your code and it also works fine, but with the same down side as Martin's. Please have a look at [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33591873/split-and-process-xml-file/33597993#comment54972307_33594772).

Comment: Size of XML is important to mention in the question.  But yes, this is doable via twig handlers. I will edit an example when next near a keyboard